# Multi platform distributed log aggregation tool

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, elastic-stack

I have a use-case to build a centralized log aggregation tool which would work with multiple platforms. Basically the suit of apps in my firm include an Angular based UI, an Ionic based Hybrid mobile app, both interaction with a Java Spring Boot Restful backend as well as a PHP based monolithic internal CRM.
Now I need a way to aggregate logs from all these applications in a centralized location filtered on the severity and the user should have access to them via a UI where he can further group and filter the logs based on App, keywords etc.

https://dzone.com/articles/distributed-logging-architecture-for-microservices

Will a solution like this work independent of the platform or the tech stacks of the Apps whose logs it is aggregating?
What other options are there?

Comment: Filebeat or Fluentd would work fine. Elasticsearch is free, so go ahead and try it.. Larger companies use Splunk for the same

Answer (score 2):

Generally I'd log to JSON. This is just a configuration in your log appender like Monolog in PHP or Logback in Spring Boot.

Then you can use Filebeat to tail those files and store them in Elasticsearch (and you don't have to do any parsing), visualize / search in Kibana, and you're done.

This is the easiest and probably also most versatile solution for the tag `elastic-stack`.